# How to increment value when they are same

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a data

By using this query  I'm getting data like this

```
Select ID,Val,Premium,Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY ID,Val ORDER BY ID) RN From Table1
```

Present Data

```
  ID    Val   Premium RN
    1   CH     201     1
    1   CH      0      1
    1   CHH    301     2
    1   CHS    401     3
```

How can I make this data to like on the present Query

```
  ID    Val   Premium RN
    1   CH     201     1
    1   CH      0      4
    1   CHH    301     2
    1   CHS    401     3
```

I just want to make the data which is same RN to increment to maximum number

**Val = CH have RN = 1 then I want to make Premium = 0 record to RN = 4**

In the present Row number I need to pick MAX(RN) and increment to that duplicate value

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET    rn = (SELECT Max(rn) + 1 
             FROM   table1) 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id 
              FROM   table1 
              WHERE  rn IN (SELECT rn 
                            FROM   table1 
                            GROUP  BY rn 
                            HAVING Count(*) > 1)) 
       AND premium = 0;
```

Update the table. Setting the new RN value to the highest value+1. Only updating the rows where there are multiple RN values and where premium is 0.

Comment: I just want to see the select query without any DML

Comment: @mohan111 Oh okay, I just tried your `select` but it's not showing the output you posted, are you sure it's correct?

Comment: please take the final output data work query on that . Forget about my given query ..

Answer (score 0):

```
     --Try This
    BEGIN TRAN
                    Declare @Strt INT,@End INT,@MaxNo INT
                    CREATE TABLE #TEMP_DATA (ID INT, VAL NVARCHAR(6),Premium INT)

                    INSERT INTO #TEMP_DATA
                    SELECT 1,'CH',201  UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1,'CH',0    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1,'CHH',301 UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1,'CHS',401  UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1,'CHHS',501 UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1,'CHHS',0 


                    SELECT ID,Val,Premium,DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY Val) RN INTO #T
                    FROM #TEMP_DATA  

                    SET @Strt=1
                    SELECT @End= MAX(RN) FROM #T 

                        WHILE @Strt<=@End  BEGIN

                                 SELECT @MaxNo=MAX(RN)+1 FROM  #T 
                                 UPDATE #T SET RN= @MaxNo WHERE  Premium=0 AND RN=@Strt

                          SET @Strt=@Strt+1

                        END

                    SELECT * FROM #T
 ROLLBACK TRAN
```